# CAML > get item by it's URL

Tags: 2007, caml-query, url

Should this CAML be working. (I tried it with u2u and it does not display the URL column.) I get this error. {System.ApplicationException} = {"One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."}

```
<Where>
 <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='URL' />
     <Value Type='URL'>/path/HR Policy.docx</Value>
 </Eq>
</Where>
```

The Following code is working after Sébastien Levert suggestion.

/path/HR Policy.docx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the  operator and the URL fields.  Can you try the Contains, it worked for me in the past!

Comment: Thanks sebastien. Worked at first attempt. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is because the URL field type stores the display text of the link as well as the link itself.